# Laravel - i try to show alert "if a data is can't be deleted because asigned in another table" instead of showing error

Tags: laravel, try-catch, alert, sql-delete, flash-message

i have a table category which is relation with table item, i try to show alert when a category data is asigned in table item when i want to delete it but it's doesn't work, the error keep on pop out and the alert doesn't appear :(

it's the error : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mystock2`.`item`, CONSTRAINT `item_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`category_id`)) (SQL: delete from `category` where `category_id` = 1)

i want to make the data which is used in another table can't be deleted and only show alert instead of error then redirect it to my intended view after that

CategoryController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;
 public function delete($category_id)
    {
        $category = \App\Category::findOrFail($category_id);
        try {
            $category->delete();
            \Session::flash('alert-success', 'success deleted');
        } catch (Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
        if($e->getCode() == "23000"){
            \Session::flash('alert-danger', 'data cant be deleted because asigned in another table');
        }}
        return redirect('/category');
    }
```

categoryform.blade.php

```
  <tbody>
    @php $no = 1; @endphp                   
    @foreach($data_category as $category)
        <tr>
            <td style="width:5%;">{{ $no++ }}</td>
            <td>{{$category->category_name}}</td>
            <td class="text-center" width="160px">
            <a href="/category/{{$category->category_id}}/edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Update
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" category-id = "{{$category->category_id}}" category-name="{{$category->category_name}}">
                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Delete
            </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
   </tbody>

<script>
    $('.delete').click(function(){
        var category_id = $(this).attr('category-id');
        var category_name = $(this).attr('category-name');
        swal({
          title: "Are you sure?",
          text: "you want to delete category with name "+category_name+" ??",
          icon: "warning",
          buttons: true,
          dangerMode: true,
        })
        .then((willDelete) => {
          if (willDelete) {
                window.location = "/category/"+category_id+"/delete";
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If category has only one relation defined you better check relation before. For instance: if(count($category->products) >0){ FLASH MESSAGE ERROR} else{ DELETE CATEGORY}

Comment: i'm sorry but i dont understand how is the code should be